# EditText in ScrollView - doesn't work scroll

Tags: android

Vertical scroll in my EditText doesn't work (I see scrollBar in widget)

```
<ScrollView ...>
    <EditText
          android:id="@+id/etCreatePredefineTaskDescription"
          style="@style/JWidget.EditText.Grey"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:gravity="start"
          android:hint="@string/description"
          android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:lines="5"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/base_dimen"
          android:scrollbars="vertical"
          android:text="@={viewModel.model.text}" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `LinearLayout`  as parent of `EditText` and then add `LinearLayout` in to `ScrollView`.

Comment: i mean inside your EditTextView wants a scroll or outside

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not working? Can you put a screenshot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16605486/7012517 is it helpful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32366372/7012517 without using scrollview..!

Answer (score 1):

In Inside want to type multiple lines use `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

Or oustide you want the scrollbars

```
<ScrollView ...>
<LinearLayout---> or <RelativeLayout-->
    <EditText
          android:id="@+id/etCreatePredefineTaskDescription"
          style="@style/JWidget.EditText.Grey"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
          android:gravity="start"
          android:hint="@string/description"
          android:imeOptions="flagNoEnterAction"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:lines="5"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/base_dimen"
          android:scrollbars="vertical"
          android:text="@={viewModel.model.text}" />
</LinearLayout> or </RelativeLayout..>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Me need both scroll types - and now, as you can see in my answer - I tried all your solutions